# Blank output in R with Warning message: [WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've encountered a problem in Rstudio (R-Markdown), whenever I knit my file it would just load a blank page. I've been using Rstudio and it has been working fine until last night.

The error/warning message is shown in the pic below. I'm kinda new so I'm hoping you could guide me to what I did wrong and what I need to do.

[Rmd with Warning message and the HTML Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMvLk.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You should provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code with this. Provide some code and you'll get help much faster :)